# Drawer layout show preview when is closed

Tags: android, material-design, drawerlayout

How can I create something like this at image from Material Design:

I would like to show little preview when is closed, what I need to do?
[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but the ‘navigation drawer’ pattern never speaks about a preview (see [here](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#)). What you see there is a permanent left bar called ‘left navigation’ (see [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#)). It is not an expandable drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [this](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library, the drawer you want named

> **Mini Drawer** and is just as the picture

or

> **PresistemntHeader Drawer** and it is as the picture and also can be expanded

Comment: Really thanks, I found something like else: [link](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)

Comment: you most welcome, and that's a nice library specially the multi-color bar, I saved it for later use